# iTunes file sharing. But sharing over http? iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a file which I want to file share. 'hello.mp3' 
At the moment the code enables file sharing if the file is in the app.
I was hoping I would be able to do it over http. So file sharing with the link instead of the sound being in the app. I want to do this because it will save memory for the user.

Here is the current code. The code allows file sharing if the file is in the app. I want it so the user will 'download' the sound from a http server such as http://test.com/hello.mp3

Thanks

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"hello.mp3", 
                                                @"hi.mp3", nil];
    for (NSString *fileName in names)
    {
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *documentDBFolderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentDBFolderPath])
        {
            NSString *resourceDBFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath toPath:documentDBFolderPath error:&error];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but that may not be allowed. In the guidelines:

**2.7 Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected.**

While an audio file may not be "code", if it is used within the app, perhaps as a language translation item, etc...I would think it would be rejected...just my 2 cents worth though.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you can "stream" content over HTTP, but if your using HTTP AND saving to the "Documents" directory to hold content you risk rejection by the app store.

If you need a workaround maybe use the "tmp" directory and save a file off a file there.  The complaint Apple has is mainly using phone data more than should be in a 3rd party application.